# Connectedness and Set Operations

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $V$ be a normed vector space and $M_n \subseteq V$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N} $. I have shown that if $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected $M_1 \cap M_2$ may not necessarily be connected and also that if   $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected with $M_1 \cap M_2 = \emptyset$ then $M_1 \cup M_2$ is connected. I am expected to prove or disprove following statements:

1. if $M_{n+1} \subseteq M_n $for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and if $M_n$ is connected then $\bigcap\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} M_n$ is also connected.
2. if $M_{n+1} \subseteq M_n $for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and if $M_n$ is connected then$\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}} M_n$ is also connected.

I believe the first statement is not generally correct but I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample as I did for the case of $M_1 \cap M_2$. As for the second statement I'm not entirely sure how I could go about constructing a proof.

Comment: Whan you wrote that $M_1\cap M_2=\emptyset$, perhaps that you meant that $M_1\cap M_2\ne\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take $M_n=\left(\left[-\frac1n,0\right)\times[-1,1]\right)\cup\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$. Then $M_n$ is connected and $M_{n+1}\subset M_n$, but $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}M_n=\{(0,1),(0,-1)\}$, which is disconnected.
2. The set $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}M_n$ is simply $M_1$, which is connected.